# How to separate a line with " " delimiter but, excluding string encapsulated in the single quotes?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, cut

This is my first post ever so please forgive me if I missed any details.

PROBLEM STATEMENT:
I have a bunch of these lines in the file. The fields are separated by space.

`'Temp.200.200B.Y2K & K-102 & P-503B.SP' (tp9012ga-bt102-734b-pqm4-kjk94kj10), PASSED, 2023-02-12T06:39:48Z, 2023-02-12T07:25:48.044Z, 1440] took 99ms including network delay.`

I would like to keep what's in the single quotes and also break these into fields with " " delimiter. The desired output is below.

`'Temp.200.200B.Y2K & K-102 & P-503B.SP' (tp9012ga-bt102-734b-pqm4-kjk94kj10), 2023-02-12T06:39:48Z, 2023-02-12T07:25:48.044Z, 99`

now keep in mind that the character inside of the single quotes varies vastly but, they are always encapsulated within single quotes.

I have tried cut with a space delimiter but, it also considers spaces in the string inside of the single quotes.
`cut -d\' -f1-6`

Also, if you notice my desired output, I also wanted to remove some fields and some characters such as 'ms' from 99ms.

Comment: Are you sure that's what your data looks like? It's strange that it has a `]` in it but no opening `[`.

Answer (score 1):

> How to separate a line with " " delimiter but, excluding string
> encapsulated in the single quotes?

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, consider following simple example, let `file.txt` content be

```
fields without quotes
'quoted field' 'another quoted field' 'yet another field'
mixed 'quoted field' unquoted
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="\047[^\047]*\047|[^ ]*"}{print "1st field is",$1; print "2nd field is",$2; print "3rd field is",$3}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
1st field is fields
2nd field is without
3rd field is quotes
1st field is 'quoted field'
2nd field is 'another quoted field'
3rd field is 'yet another field'
1st field is mixed
2nd field is 'quoted field'
3rd field is unquoted
```

Explanation: I use `FPAT` to inform GNU `AWK` what constitutes field, namely single quote (as `'` is used as terminator I use `\047` which is ASCII code of that character in octal) followed by zero-or-more non-quotes followed by single quote OR (`|`) zero-or-more non-space characters. **Disclaimer**: this solution assumes `'` are perfectly balanced and there is never `'` inside quoted field which is non-terminating.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/'\''[^'\'']*'\''|\S+/&\n/g
        s/.*/echo "&"|sed -n "1,2p;4,5p;8s#ms##p"/e
        s/\n//g' file
```

Prepend newlines to space delimiters.

Using the evaluation within the substitution command, run a second invocation of sed and treat each field as a line.

Remove or amend the lines (fields).

Remove the inserted newlines.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the problem statement and the desired output, you may need to go for `,` as delimiter along with a combination of `awk` and `sed`.

I will simply echo your *PROBLEM STATEMENT* string in this case to show you how it can be done.
I am assuming the line format is the same in your file (no issues with characters inside the quote changing vastly except for `,`)

```
echo "'Temp.200.200B.Y2K & K-102 & P-503B.SP' (tp9012ga-bt102-734b-pqm4-kjk94kj10), PASSED, 2023-02-12T06:39:48Z, 2023-02-12T07:25:48.044Z, 1440] took 99ms including network delay." | awk -F "," '{print $1,","$3","$4","$5}' | sed -e 's/ms .*//g' -e 's/[0-9]*] took //g'
```

**The Output:**

```
'Temp.200.200B.Y2K & K-102 & P-503B.SP' (tp9012ga-bt102-734b-pqm4-kjk94kj10) , 2023-02-12T06:39:48Z, 2023-02-12T07:25:48.044Z, 99
```

**EDIT:**
@Ed Morton - I tried your approach and you are right. It can be done using awk only as well. The command is given below.

```
echo "'Temp.200.200B.Y2K & K-102 & P-503B.SP' (tp9012ga-bt102-734b-pqm4-kjk94kj10), PASSED, 2023-02-12T06:39:48Z, 2023-02-12T07:25:48.044Z, 1440] took 99ms including network delay." | awk -F "," '{ gsub("[0-9]*] took ","",$5); gsub("ms .*","",$5); print $1,","$3","$4","$5}'
```

Comment: You never need sed when you're using awk. `awk -F "," '{print $1,","$3","$4","$5}' | sed -e 's/ms .*//g' -e 's/[0-9]*] took //g'` = `awk -F "," '{$0=$1" ,"$3","$4","$5; gsub(/ms .*/,""); gsub([0-9]*] took /,""); print}'`.

Comment: @EdMorton I tried your command but it gave me an error. `1 is invalid as number of arguments for gsub`. Anyways, I got your point and I have edited my post to add your method of using awk only. Thanks to you I learnt something new today. :)

Comment: `gsub([0-9]*]...` should be `gsub(/[0-9]*]...`. The regexp delimiter in awk is `/`, not `"`. You're welcome.

Comment: @EdMorton `"` worked for me fine. Using GNU Awk 4.0.2

Comment: `"` is a string delimiter. When you use a string like `"foo"` in a regexp context it's considered a dynamic regexp so it has to first be interpreted to become a regexp and then interpreted again when used as the regexp so it's inefficient and requires additional escaping and other considerations compared to a static regexp `/foo/`.