# Regex in bash: extract string with single or double quotes

Tags: wordpress, bash, grep

I would like to extract database access information from a wordpress wp-config.php file.

Example (double quotes):

```
define( "DB_NAME", "mydatabase" );
```

But it might as well look like this (single quotes)

```
define( 'DB_NAME', 'mydatabase' );
```

A mixed version is also possible:

```
define( 'DB_NAME', "mydatabase" );
```

So far I have found this on the internet:

```
DBNAME=`cat wp-config.php | grep DB_NAME | cut -d \' -f 4`
```

This works when single quotes are used. What I am looking for is a regex that would handle all cases.

Thank you

Comment: Can't you run `php` to run the config and output the values for you?

Comment: Not in my usecase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Input file

```
$ cat wp-config.php
define( 'DB_NAME', "mydatabase" );
```

or

```
$ cat wp-config.php
define( 'DB_NAME', 'mydatabase" );
```

##### With [php](/questions/tagged/php):

```
php -r 'require_once("wp-config.php"); echo DB_NAME;'
```

##### With `GNU grep`:

```
$ grep -oP "^define.*?DB_NAME.*?[\042\047]\K[\w.]+" wp-config.php
```

##### Output

```
mydatabase
```

Comment: Thx. Almost. When the databasename contains dots (e.g. www.mydatabase.com) your GNU grep example will only return "www".

Comment: Usually, the way to thanks here it's to vote up++. Anyway, post edited accordingly. Have you tested the better `php` approach?

Comment: I tried but my reputation does not allow me to.

Comment: Or to accept the answer, that you can ;) PlusPlus'ed you anyway ;)

Comment: I am not that quick. Your final edit nailed it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about `awk` ?

**Your example File:**

```
$ cat wp-config.php
define( 'DB_NAME', "mydatabase.com" );
```

**The Command:**

```
awk -F "['\"]" '/DB_NAME/{print $4}' wp-config.php
```

**The Output:**

`mydatabase.com`

Comment: This is a useless use of `grep`. `awk -F "['\"]" '/DB_NAME/{print $4}'`

Comment: [As mentioned previously about sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75498295/how-to-separate-a-line-with-delimiter-but-excluding-string-encapsulated-in/75507587#comment133225271_75507587), you also never need `grep` when you're using `awk`. Any time you find yourself piping between grep and/or sed and/or awk, think twice as you can almost certainly do it better with a single call to awk.